# Django: Filtering children of children of model for use within view/template

Tags: django

We have the following model structure:

- Parent (name, slug, country, children[ManyToMany on Child])
- Child
  (name, country, children[ManyToMany on Grandchild])
- Grandchild (name,
  country)

Now, in my view, I want to make sure we are only dealing with data for the current country (country=kwargs["country"]) at all levels.  Now, I have been using the following (obfuscated code) in order to filter the children.  This allows me to simply reference "children" in the template in order to access the filtered child records, however I'm having trouble determining a best-practice solution for applying this same filtering at the grandchild level.

Below is an example of what is working for filtering children, but how do I perform this same filtering within the template when looping through the grandchildren?  I don't want a front-end developer to have to understand the data structure - ideally, I would want them to be able to loop through children, and within that loop, loop through child.grandchildren, which will already be filtered.

**View class:**

```
class ParentView(DetailView):
    model = Parent

    def get_object(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs["slug"], country=self.kwargs["country"])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ParentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context["children"] = self.object.children.filter(country=self.country)

        return context
```

**Template sample:**

```
{% for child in children %}
    <li>{{child.name}}
         <ul>
             {# This list of grandchildren is NOT filtered #}
             {% for grandchild in child.children%}
                 <li>{{grandchild.name}}</li>
             {% endfor %}
         </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

In the template:

```
{% for child in children %}
    <li>{{ child.name }}
         <ul>
            {% for grandchild in child.children.all %}
                <li>{{ grandchild.name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
         </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your code is simply setting a single context entry 'grandchildren' over and over again, constantly overwriting the value - I do not believe this will work, but I do thank you for your effort.

Comment: @Keith - you right. When I tested the for loop was no good. I updated my answer. Maybe it'll help.